# How to use describe() for a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I use the `describe` function for a pandas dataframe? I need to get statistical information (mean, standard deviation, etc) for one variable of the data frame, but specifically for two groups of another variable.

So basically there is a column called "X" that contains numbers and another column called "Y" that contains categories like "full" and "empty". And I need to use `describe()` to get the information.

I know how the get the information of X using `df.X.describe()` but not from the rest.

UPDATE:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzvNj.png) I want to know the statistical information of the "model_type_index" based on the "mfr_code", so for ASX and MBX

Comment: You'd like stats info for string data?  I'm not sure I follow. Can you please update the question with some data examples and expected result, please?

Comment: Thanks for the update. Although not specific to the updated example, the answer posted below should put you on the right track. If not, give me a shout.  (Additionally, would you mind removing the image and pasting the example data as text. It's tough to copy/paste data from an image.)  Cheers.

Comment: @S3DEV yeah sorry, I´m new here and not sure how everything works. Thank you for your comments!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using the `.groupby()` function on the `DataFrame` and passing the column name to be grouped; in this case `'y'`.

Sample data setup:

```
# Setup
x = list(range(10))
y = ['full', 'empty']*5
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})
```

Example usage:

```
# Describe the groups of data, based on Y.
df.groupby('y').describe().reset_index()
```

Output:
The results show the stats data for column `'x'`, where the values have been grouped by column `'y'`.

```
       y     x                                        
         count mean       std  min  25%  50%  75%  max
0  empty   5.0  5.0  3.162278  1.0  3.0  5.0  7.0  9.0
1   full   5.0  4.0  3.162278  0.0  2.0  4.0  6.0  8.0
```

Sample DataFrame:

```
   x      y
0  0   full
1  1  empty
2  2   full
3  3  empty
4  4   full
5  5  empty
6  6   full
7  7  empty
8  8   full
9  9  empty
```

Comment: My pleasure, glad it's working for you.  (As a standard SO practice, may I ask that you click the tick next to the answer to show it's been accepted?). Cheers mate.